# How to update a map with map data from API in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

I am new to Flutter and finding it difficult to update `_users` with a map I get from API. I get build errors even though no actual errors are shown in VSCode.

Here is my code.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Users with ChangeNotifier {
  final String id;
  final String firstName;
  final String lastName;
  final String emailAddress;
  final String phoneNumber;
  final String classId;
  final String roleId;
  final String dateCreated;
  final String uid;
  bool isActive;
  final String profilePhoto;

  Users({
    required this.id,
    required this.firstName,
    required this.lastName,
    required this.emailAddress,
    required this.phoneNumber,
    required this.classId,
    required this.roleId,
    required this.dateCreated,
    required this.uid,
    required this.isActive,
    required this.profilePhoto,
  });

  Map<String, Users> _users = {};

  Map<String, Users> get users {
    return {..._users};
  }

  Future<void> fetchUser() async {
    try {
      final String idToken =
          await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.getIdToken();

      final reauthUrl = Uri.parse(
          'https://example-backend.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/User/reauth');

      final reauthResponse = await http.post(reauthUrl,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
          },
          body: json.encode({"token": idToken}));

      final returnedTokenData =
          json.decode(reauthResponse.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;

      final serverToken = returnedTokenData['token'];

      final url =
          Uri.parse('https://example-backend.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/User');

      final response = await http.get(
        url,
        headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer $serverToken'},
      );

      final responseData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      Map<String, dynamic> userData = {};
      userData.update(id, (value) {
        return Users(
          id: responseData['id'],
          firstName: responseData['firstName'],
          lastName: responseData['lastName'],
          emailAddress: responseData['emailAddress'],
          phoneNumber: responseData['phoneNumber'],
          classId: responseData['classId'],
          roleId: responseData['roleId'],
          dateCreated: responseData['dateCreated'],
          uid: responseData['uid'],
          isActive: responseData['isActive'],
          profilePhoto: responseData['profilePhoto'],
        );
      });
      print(userData);

      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what build errors are you getting? try to reload vscode, this will cause dart analyzer to restart. also check if you're not filtering errors shown in vscode.

Comment: Not sure if that causing any problem, but the use of `userData.update` seems really weird to me. Why not just do userData[id] = Users(...) ?

Comment: Also, in advance, you should notice that responseData['id'], for instance, is not a String, it is a String? (nullable). If any of these fields are null, then your app should throw an Exception while reading responseData and cause your app to crash, because id cannot be null in your Users class

Comment: @EricOmine. Thanks for your reply. I actually got rid of the build error by adding null check on the variables in the Users class and replacing 'required' with '@required' in the constructor. The build error was caused by the main.dart file needing arguments for those parameters as the Class is being called on the routes table. The actual problem now is that the code does not work for updating the map.

Comment: Method update means updating a specific value in the map that can be read by key that you pass in the first argument of the update method.
But your userData is empty and cannot be updated because it doesn't have any values.

Comment: @Cliff if you're using required with @ than you're using an old version of Flutter, you should probably update it.

Comment: @AlexShinkevich Ohh I see. What I intend to do is assign the data fetched from the API to the variables in the Users class. How can I acheive that? Thank you

Comment: @EricOmine I am using Flutter version 2.10.4

Comment: Do I understand right that you want to fetch info about current user by idToken?

Comment: @AlexShinkevich Yes, I want to fetch info about current user by IdToken. That's correct.

Comment: Ok. So I would suggest two ways.
1. You could avoid using maps and you could make all your fields not final. After getting info from the backend you could just initialize all your variables.
I mean you can remove using userData.update and just call
id: responseData['id'] etc

2. You can define a class for User and change your notifier something like that:
class UserNotifier extends ChangeNotifier{
  User? user;

void fetch() {
  /// fetch data...

  user = User(
    id: responseData['id'], 
    ...
  );

  notifyListeners();
}

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to fix the issue is to not use maps and assign the values from the API directly to the variables in your class. The variables should not be final to be able to reassign values to them.

```
final responseData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
id = responseData['id'];
      firstName = responseData['firstName'];
      lastName = responseData['lastName'];
      emailAddress = responseData['emailAddress'];
      phoneNumber = responseData['phoneNumber'];
      classId = responseData['classId'];
      roleId = responseData['roleId'];
      dateCreated = responseData['dateCreated'];
      uid = responseData['uid'];
      isActive = responseData['isActive'];
      profilePhoto = responseData['profilePhoto'];
```